# css - how to center the span text in rounded button

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-haibt-1bnib?file=/src/main.js

[image]

I want to center the `-` text in the button, but I cannot find a way to do it.

html

```
  <button class="round-button align-middle mr-1">
    <span>-</span>
  </button>
```

css

```
.round-button {
  min-width: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.round-button:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I saw your code sandbox and it looks like the text is centered, but you need to increase the width of you button .

Comment: @Random COSMOS please check my image above

Comment: use display flex

Comment: do you mean center vertically, if so then as  Muzamil301 said use display: flex; and align-items; center;

Comment: I believe @Rahul Kapuriya answer is more complete and descriptive and should be chosen as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html

```
<button class="round-button align-middle mr-1">-</button>
```

css

```
.round-button {
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 20px; // to center text vertically
}
```

You just need to add the same `line-height` as your button's height and don't need an extra span element to add text. I've also removed unnecessary styles.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `line-height: 20px` to that. If it still looks off, you might be using a custom font with non-standard line height. In this case play with the line-height property until it looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style properties to `.round-button`:

```
.round-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And, remove style for `.round-button:before`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.round-button {
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 48px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
  <button class="round-button">
    <span>-</span>
  </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `<span>-</span>` to `<span style="position:relative; left:0px; top:-3px">-</span>`. If it doesn't look right you can play around with it.